# Arduino programming attiny13a

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, bootloader

Hello I want to program an Attiny13a with Arduino code. I always have this error  when I add repository "no file board.txt" in path.
How to successfully configure IDE to able burn on it?

I use :
[Link 1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ard-core13/?source=typ_redirect)
And :
[Link 2](https://github.com/jensh/attiny13a)
But nothing changed .

I am using IDE Arduino v1.6.7.

Finally I import ATTiny13 [(link)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ard-core13/) now these errors appear:

```
Board attiny13:avr:attiny13 doesn't define a 'build.board'
preference.Auto-set to: AVR_ATTINY13

Board attiny13:avr:attiny13at4 doesn't define a 'build.board' preference. Auto-set to: AVR_ATTINY13AT4

Board attiny13:avr:attiny13at9 doesn't define a 'build.board' preference. Auto-set to: AVR_ATTINY13AT9

Warning: platform.txt from core 'Attiny13' contains deprecated compiler.path={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avr/bin/, automatically converted to compiler.path={runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path}/bin/. Consider upgrading this core.

Warning: platform.txt from core 'Attiny13' contains deprecated tools.avrdude.cmd.path={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude, automatically converted to tools.avrdude.cmd.path={path}/bin/avrdude. Consider upgrading this core.


Warning: platform.txt from core 'Attiny13' contains deprecated tools.avrdude.config.path={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf, automatically converted to tools.avrdude.config.path={path}/etc/avrdude.conf. Consider upgrading this core.

Warning: platform.txt from core 'Attiny13' contains deprecated recipe.ar.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.ar.cmd}" {compiler.ar.flags} {compiler.ar.extra_flags} "{build.path}/{archive_file}" "{object_file}", automatically converted to recipe.ar.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.ar.cmd}" {compiler.ar.flags} {compiler.ar.extra_flags} "{archive_file_path}" "{object_file}". Consider upgrading this core.
```

Comment: @Gerben Please, give him a break, he's non-native english speaker.

Comment: Could you please include the actual error message exactly as it was displayed in the IDE?

Comment: I want to apologize Gerben if my english is bad but i write it after 16h in work . I will try to edit post when i sleep a little.

Comment: @MichałGałkowski The "errors" (they're warnings) should not matter. It should still compile and upload.